# iTextSharp center align objects within the Document object

Tags: c#, .net, itext

Is there a quick and simple way to center align objects within the Document object?  **Without** performing any calculation logic, ie. Get width of page, get width of contents, divide by two, etc.

I have a PdfPTable object within a Paragraph object, within the Document object.  I would like to center the Paragraph object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
PDFPTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
```

Comment: It is not working, maybe you mean to `ALIGN_CENTER` instead of `CENTER_ALIGN`

Answer (score 41):

the equivalent replacement for iTextSharp :

```
paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
```

or try this way

```
paragraph.IndentationRight = 100;
paragraph.IndentationLeft = 100;
```

Comment: Correct iTextSharp syntax versus iText

Answer (score 8):

this iText (probably same for iTextSharp):

```
paragraph.setAlignment( Element.ALIGN_CENTER );
```

and you might want to set the indentation so that it sits nicely:

```
paragraph.setIndentationLeft( 100 );
paragraph.setIndentationRight( 100 );
```

Comment: It seems to be squishing the table.  Do you have a way to stop it from doing so?

Comment: are you using the two setIndentation methods above? Reduce the indentation sizes or remove them completely.

Comment: PDFPTable has setWidthPercentage and setTotalWidth methods, which may help you

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  The indentation methods seem to squish the tables themselves.  I did try the setWidthPercentage and setTotalWidth methods as you suggested, but they weren't the exact solutions I was looking for.  I'm actually onto another scenario now, where I'm trying to set the paragraph width to the width of the gridview from which it's populated, but I'm having some issues.  Please see my other question if you get the chance.  Thanks!

Comment: Here's my other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928015/itextsharp-paragraph-size

Answer (score 2):

For image alignment:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(MapPath("~/images/HKVictoriaHarbour.png"));
image1.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
doc.Add(image1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to align paragraph will be I think

```
Dim para = New Paragraph("Header")
    para.SpacingBefore = 20
    para.SpacingAfter = 20
    para.Alignment = 1 '0-Left, 1 middle,2 Right
    Document.Add(para)
```

Answer (score -2):

To do something like this

[image: To do something like this]

this is the code

```
Sub Crea_Contrato_PDF()
    Dim T0 As String = "CONTRATO INDIVIDUAL DE TRABAJO " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    Dim T1 As String = "JORGE MARIO DEL CID SANCHEZ de cincuenta y un años de edad, casado, guatemalteco, Licenciado, con domicilio en el departamento de Guatemala, con dirección en séptima avenida once guión sesenta y tres zona nueve edificio Galerías España; con Documento Personal De Identificación (DPI) código único número 1766 73121 0101 extendido por el Registro Nacional de las Personas “ & "RENAP" & ”, actuando en representación de la entidad SAFARI SEGURIDAD, SOCIEDAD ANÓNIMA ubicada en granja Rosilú kilómetro noventa y uno punto cinco municipio de Santa Lucía Cotzumalguapa del departamento de Escuintla, por una parte; y por la otra: "

    '        Dim T2 As String = " de " & TextBox72.Text & " años de edad, sexo "
    Dim t3 As String = " con nacionalidad guatemalteca, con dirección en "

    Dim t3a As String = " con Documento Personal de Identificación código único número "

    Dim t4 As String = " del Registro Nacional de las Personas –RENAP-; quienes para los efectos de este contrato se denominarán empleador o empresa y trabajador o empleado respectivamente; celebrando el CONTRATO INDIVIDUAL DE TRABAJO contenido en las siguientes cláusulas: "

    Dim T5 As String = " La relación de trabajo inicia el: "

    'Dim T6 As String = " SEGUNDA: El trabajador prestará los servicios de: " & TextBox61.Text
    Dim T6 As String = " El trabajador prestará los servicios de: "

    ' Dim T7 As String = " TERCERA: Los servicios serán prestados en: uno de los distintos puntos o puestos dentro de la República de Guatemala en donde la empresa brinda sus servicios."

    Dim T7 As String = " Los servicios serán prestados en: uno de los distintos puntos o puestos dentro de la República de Guatemala en donde la empresa brinda sus servicios."

    'Dim T8 As String = " CUARTA: La vigencia o duración del presente contrato es por tiempo indefinido. "
    Dim T8 As String = " La vigencia o duración del presente contrato es por tiempo indefinido. "

    'Dim T9 As String = " QUINTA: La jornada de trabajo será así: de lunes a viernes de seis a catorce horas, y día sábado de seis a diez horas, para complementar las 44 horas de la jornada semanal; dicha jornada es meramente enunciada y no taxativa ya que por la naturaleza de los servicios que la empresa presta se podrá modificar la misma previo acuerdo con el trabajador, velando siempre que no se contravengan los derechos que las leyes laborales otorguen a éste. "
    Dim T9 As String = " La jornada de trabajo será así: de lunes a viernes de seis a catorce horas, y día sábado de seis a diez horas, para complementar las 44 horas de la jornada semanal; dicha jornada es meramente enunciada y no taxativa ya que por la naturaleza de los servicios que la empresa presta se podrá modificar la misma previo acuerdo con el trabajador, velando siempre que no se contravengan los derechos que las leyes laborales otorguen a éste. "

    Dim T10 As String = " El salario será de "
    Dim T10A As String = " mensuales más la Bonificación Incentivo de Decreto 37-2001 del Congreso de la República por "

    Dim T10B As String = ". El mismo se cancelará el último día de cada mes, en las instalaciones de la empresa por medio cheque bancario o depositado a la cuenta bancaria del trabajador, conforme el artículo 3 del Convenio Internacional de Trabajo ratificado por la República de Guatemala y el artículo 102 literal t) de la Constitución Política de la República. "

    'Dim T11 As String = " SEPTIMA: Las horas extras, el séptimo y los días de asueto, le serán pagados de conformidad con los artículos 121, 124, 126 y 127 del Código de Trabajo. "
    Dim T11 As String = " Las horas extras, el séptimo y los días de asueto, le serán pagados de conformidad con los artículos 121, 124, 126 y 127 del Código de Trabajo. "

    'Dim T12 As String = " OCTAVA: Debido a la naturaleza especial de la actividad de la empresa la cual brinda seguridad privada a personas jurídicas o individuales, conforme el artículo 136 del Código de Trabajo el empleador podrá dividir el período de vacaciones en dos partes como máximo por la índole especial mencionada. "
    Dim T12 As String = " Debido a la naturaleza especial de la actividad de la empresa la cual brinda seguridad privada a personas jurídicas o individuales, conforme el artículo 136 del Código de Trabajo el empleador podrá dividir el período de vacaciones en dos partes como máximo por la índole especial mencionada. "

    Dim T13 As String = " El trabajador se compromete a cumplir todas las obligaciones que le atañe e impone la Ley que Regula los Servicios de Seguridad Privada según DECRETO NÚMERO 52-2010 DEL CONGRESO DE LA REPÚBLICA DE GUATEMALA; y en caso de incumplimiento a una de tales disposiciones se considera falta grave en el trabajo y la empresa podrá dar finalizada la relación laboral con el trabajador sin responsabilidad alguna para la misma. "

    'Dim T14 As String = " DÉCIMA: Es entendido que de conformidad con los artículos 122 y 124 del Código de trabajo la jornada ordinaria y extraordinaria no puede exceder de una suma total de 12 horas diarias.  El presente contrato se suscribe en Granja Rosilú kilómetro noventa y uno punto cinco carretera del Pacífico municipio de Santa Lucía Cotzumalguapa del departamento de Escuintla; a los " & TextBox16.Text & " días del mes de " & TextBox17.Text & " del año dos mil dieciséis"
    Dim T14 As String = " Es entendido que de conformidad con los artículos 122 y 124 del Código de trabajo la jornada ordinaria y extraordinaria no puede exceder de una suma total de 12 horas diarias.  El presente contrato se suscribe en Granja Rosilú kilómetro noventa y uno punto cinco, carretera del Pacífico, municipio de Santa Lucía Cotzumalguapa del departamento de Escuintla; a los _____ días del mes de __________________ del año __________." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    Dim T15 As String = "                                        ___________________________           _________________________" & vbCrLf
    Dim T16 As String = "                                                     Empleador                                               Trabajador" & vbCrLf

    Dim txt_cc As String = "CONTRATO_CC_" & txt_CCosto.Text & "_EMP_" & TextBox1.Text & ".pdf"

    ''//The main folder that we are working in
    Dim WorkingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

    ''//The file that we are creating
    'Dim WorkingFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, txt_FileName.Text)
    Dim WorkingFile = Path.Combine("D:\CONTRATOS\", txt_cc)

    'Dim SampleImage = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "LOGO_c.PNG")
    Dim SampleImage = Path.Combine("C:\Aplicaciones\SafariSis\", "LOGO_c.PNG")

    ''//Create our file with an exclusive writer lock
    Using FS As New FileStream(WorkingFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
        ''//Create our PDF document
        Using Doc As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
            ''//Bind our PDF object to the physical file using a PdfWriter
            Using Writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS)
                ''//Open our document for writing
                Doc.Open()

                ''//Insert a blank page
                Doc.NewPage()

                ''//Create a PDF image object from our physical image
                Dim ThisImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(SampleImage)

                ''//Use standard ratio resizing algorithms to calculate new image dimensions based on the documents dimensions. This will shrink or grow documents to fit

                ''//Will hold our new image dimensions
                ''//Documents sometimes have margins (and this sample does) so subtract them so that our image in centered in the page
                Dim NewW, NewH As Single

                NewW = Doc.PageSize.Width - (Doc.LeftMargin + Doc.RightMargin)
                NewH = Doc.PageSize.Height - (Doc.TopMargin + Doc.BottomMargin)

                ''//Scale the image
                '  ThisImage.ScaleToFit(NewW, NewH)

                ''//Add the image to the document ****************************
                'Doc.Add(ThisImage)

                Dim ppp0 As New Paragraph(T0, LFont2)
                ppp0.Font.Size = 12
                ppp0.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
                ppp0.Font = LFont2
                Doc.Add(ppp0)

                Dim ppp1 As New Chunk(T1, LFont)
                ppp1.Font.Size = 10
                Dim ppp2 As New Chunk(TextBox74.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp3 As New Chunk(" de ", LFont)
                Dim ppp4 As New Chunk(TextBox72.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp5 As New Chunk(" años de edad, sexo ", LFont)
                Dim ppp6 As New Chunk(TextBox71.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp7 As New Chunk(" estado civil ", LFont)
                Dim ppp8 As New Chunk(TextBox70.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp9 As New Chunk(t3, LFont)
                Dim ppp9A As New Chunk(TextBox69.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp10 As New Chunk(" vecino de ", LFont)
                Dim ppp11 As New Chunk(TextBox68.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp12 As New Chunk(t3a, LFont)
                Dim ppp13 As New Chunk(TextBox67.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp14 As New Chunk(t4, LFont)
                Dim ppp15 As New Chunk(" PRIMERA:", LFont2)
                Dim ppp16 As New Chunk(T5, LFont)
                Dim ppp17 As New Chunk(TextBox66.Text & ".  SEGUNDA:", LFont2)
                Dim ppp18 As New Chunk(T6, LFont)
                Dim ppp19 As New Chunk(TextBox61.Text & ".  TERCERA:", LFont2)
                Dim ppp20 As New Chunk(T7, LFont)
                Dim ppp21 As New Chunk(" CUARTA: ", LFont2)
                Dim ppp22 As New Chunk(T8, LFont)
                Dim ppp23 As New Chunk(" QUINTA: ", LFont2)
                Dim ppp24 As New Chunk(T9, LFont)
                Dim ppp25 As New Chunk(" SEXTA: ", LFont2)
                Dim ppp26 As New Chunk(T10, LFont)
                Dim ppp27 As New Chunk(TextBox65.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp28 As New Chunk(T10A, LFont)
                Dim ppp29 As New Chunk(TextBox64.Text, LFont2)
                Dim ppp30 As New Chunk(T10B, LFont)
                Dim ppp31 As New Chunk(" SEPTIMA: ", LFont2)
                Dim ppp32 As New Chunk(T11, LFont)
                Dim ppp33 As New Chunk(" OCTAVA: ", LFont2)
                Dim ppp34 As New Chunk(T12, LFont)
                Dim ppp35 As New Chunk(" NOVENA: ", LFont2)
                Dim ppp36 As New Chunk(T13, LFont)

                Dim ppp37 As New Chunk(" DECIMA: ", LFont2)
                Dim ppp38 As New Chunk(T14, LFont)

                Dim ppp39 As New Chunk(T15, LFont)
                Dim ppp40 As New Chunk(T16, LFont)

                ppp15.Font.Size = 10
                ppp16.Font.Size = 10
                ppp17.Font.Size = 10
                ppp18.Font.Size = 10
                ppp19.Font.Size = 10
                ppp20.Font.Size = 10
                ppp21.Font.Size = 10
                ppp22.Font.Size = 10

                Dim ppp00 As New Chunk("", LFont)
                ppp1.Font.Size = 10

                Dim body As New Phrase(12, ppp00)

                body.Add(ppp1)
                body.Add(ppp2)
                body.Add(ppp3)
                body.Add(ppp4)
                body.Add(ppp5)
                body.Add(ppp6)
                body.Add(ppp7)
                body.Add(ppp8)
                body.Add(ppp9)
                body.Add(ppp9A)
                body.Add(ppp10)
                body.Add(ppp11)
                body.Add(ppp12)
                body.Add(ppp13)
                body.Add(ppp14)
                body.Add(ppp15)
                body.Add(ppp16)
                body.Add(ppp17)
                body.Add(ppp18)
                body.Add(ppp19)
                body.Add(ppp20)
                body.Add(ppp21)
                body.Add(ppp22)
                body.Add(ppp23)
                body.Add(ppp24)
                body.Add(ppp25)
                body.Add(ppp26)
                body.Add(ppp27)
                body.Add(ppp28)
                body.Add(ppp29)
                body.Add(ppp30)
                body.Add(ppp31)
                body.Add(ppp32)
                body.Add(ppp33)
                body.Add(ppp34)
                body.Add(ppp35)
                body.Add(ppp36)
                body.Add(ppp37)
                body.Add(ppp38)
                body.Add(ppp39)
                body.Add(ppp40)

                Dim p As New Paragraph(" ", LFont)
                p.Font.Size = 10
                p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED

                p.Add(body)
                Doc.Add(p)

                ''//Close our document
                Doc.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Way to much detail.  Please shorten your code to the important parts and include a better description of your question.